# Oracledb query for the following usecase

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I have an Availability table like below

```
AVAIL_DATE | AVAILABLE
```

AVAIL_DATE represents stay date and AVAILABLE is a char with 'T' or 'F'.

I need to check whether the availability table has true for all the dates within a given range (START_DATE, END_DATE)

I know I can achieve it like below queries

```
Operate to check whether it's all true 

    Select AVAILABLE from AVAILABILITY 
    where AVAIL_DATE BETWEEN (START_DATE, END_DATE);
```

I cannot figure out the Operate part and also I am not sure of the optimal oracledb query for this use case as I am a newbie to PL/SQL

Can someone help me with the query for this ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: I have edited to show my research @user7294900

Comment: Hi Aarish.  The solution to this will depend on the structure of table AVAILABILITY.  Is there always exactly one row for every date in the range, or could there be gaps.  And will column available always have either 'T' or 'F' or could there be NULLS / other values?

Comment: You should not use reserved word (like `DATE`) for column names. Better use something like `AVAIL_DATE`

Comment: @ChristianPalmer The table has row for every date and available will only have T or F only

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Okay i will edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count that the number of `T` values equals the number of dates:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN COUNT( CASE available WHEN 'T' THEN 1 END ) = COUNT(*)
       THEN 'All days available'
       ELSE 'Not available'
       END AS is_available
FROM   AVAILABILITY 
WHERE  DATE BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE;
```

Comment: I want only the boolean whether it's available for all dates

Comment: @AarishRamesh There is no Boolean data type in SQL - you will need to use another encoding (i.e. `1`/`0` or `T`/`F` or `All days available`/`Not available`) to represent your Boolean - just replace the literals I have used with the literals you want to use to represent your truthy/falsy values.

Answer (score -1):

Read below at your convenience, but here is your TRUE / FALSE ...

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM AVAILABLE
 WHERE AVAIL_DATE BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE
   AND AVAILABLE = 'F'
```

If the return count is greater than 0 your condition is FALSE

READ BELOW AT YOUR CONVENIENCE ... IS USEFUL
First, PL/SQL is an entire language like C/Java/C++/C# with BULK COLLECT INTO clause (which you may need here) and several other parts ... big learning ahead.  Yes, that may sound "not contributing but critising", but read on for real detail.

You specify a column with the name DATE.  Since DATE is a reserved word in OracleDB, I advise changing the column name to AVAIL_DATE.

The SQL for Oracle will look like

```
SELECT AVAILABLE
  FROM AVAILABLE
 WHERE AVAIL_DATE BETWEEN START_DATE and END DATE
```

But you will likely receive both T and F as a result because there will be both in a date range, which is either a CURSOR in PL/SQL or the PL/SQL statement could read as

```
SELECT AVAILABLE
  BULK COLLECT INTO collection_of_type_char_1
  FROM AVAILABLE
 WHERE AVAIL_DATE BETWEEN START_DATE and END DATE
```

Learning about collections ("collection_of_type_char_1" above) in PL/SQL is really something you can only do yourself.